# How do you access a subdomain on localhost with VMWare Fusion on a Mac?

Tags: mac, windows, dns

I am able to [access localhost on a Mac through Windows XP on VMWare Fusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61449/how-do-i-access-the-host-from-vmware-fusion) by using my Mac username like this:

```
http://username.local:3000/
```

But how do I do that with a subdomain, something like this:

```
http://username.subdomain.local:3000/
```

Any ideas?

I am able to access subdomains on my Mac no problem, by adding things like `blog.localhost` to `/etc/hosts`.  What is the equivalent on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate to `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc` where the 'hosts' file is located.